# How can I send post request with base64 image?

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, postman

I am making an image upload component in vue js with custom cropping option. The cropped version is being saved in my state as a base64 string. This is it:

```
data:image/png;base64,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....
```

now I am trying to send this image to my node js server using post request API. In Postman, I am writing the body selecting "raw" and "json" in this the body in this way:

```
{
        "image" : "data:image/png;base64,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.....
}
```

The request not detecting this json data in the body and returning error:

```
{
    "image": "\"image\" is required"
}
```

Also tried the form_data sending method in this way:

```
var axios = require('axios');
      var FormData = require('form-data');
      // var fs = require('fs');
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('image', formdata.logoFinalImage);

      var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: myurl,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': this.state.token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: data
      };

      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Same issue.
How can I send the final cropped version to the node api endpoint?

Comment: I think you are not creating a base64 URL instead it is a mere meta data. You can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360403/uploading-a-base64-encoded-image-to-node-js-server-not-working

Comment: could you add postman screen shot how you are adding it , and do your product except the data as form or json body ?

Comment: @PDHide JSON body. Here is the SS: https://ibb.co/g4bTDMp

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I am using this string for previewing the image in my vue js front end. And this string is being generated by using readAsDataURL(file) function. Is there anything else to do to make it base64?

Comment: @PDHide also tried the form-data way. Post Updated Accordingly

Comment: Are you able to make it work in postman ?

Comment: @PDHide nope. in postman when I am uploading file in formdata, it is working. but when I am trying to replace the fs.createStream function with my base64 string, it is not working. Also, to check if my base64 string is actually ok, i have pasted that string in an online base64 to image converter, and its generating image just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue. There were two ways of doing it. One is required changes in the backend to configure the code in a way that can receive base64 and convert it to image. Reference: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-upload-base64-images-in-vue-nodejs-4e89635daebc

Other is to make the base64 image file, and then send it to the backend as form-data. Used this one for my case. Reference of this solution: https://gist.github.com/ibreathebsb/a104a9297d5df4c8ae944a4ed149bcf1

Answer (score 1):

if its working in postman then you can create the code from postman itself , select code and search for axios

v8<

[image]

if using v8

[image]

Comment: yes i can do that. but the thing is as i am making the image in my front end in base64 format, i need to send the base64 string instead of the image file you sent there. That is not working. That's the issue